# Snippet to generate today's date in YAML header of Quarto doc in VS Code using Python

Tags: visual-studio-code, quarto, vscode-snippets

When using Quarto in RStudio I use a snippet to generate a YAML header that prints today's date automatically using the following R code

```
snippet headerq
    ---
    date: "`r Sys.Date()`"
    ---
```

Using this `headerq` snippet will generate the following header:

```
---
date: "2024-03-03"
---
```

How can I achieve this same functionality when using Quarto docs in Python in VSCode?

Comment: https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/userdefinedsnippets#_variables

Comment: Unfortutely R documents only have a YAML header, if the second `---` would instead be `--- |` you could actually parse it with a compliant yaml parser as a multi-document YAML stream. The only restriction being that the R code cannot contain `---` anywere at the beginnng of a line. (My ruamel.yaml can parse that, PyYAML is not compliant, as it erroneously requires the root level literal style scalar to be indented)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Saving the following snippet worked exactly as needed.

```
{
"Quarto Header": {
    "scope": "",
    "prefix": "headerqp",
    "body": [
    "---",
    "date: $CURRENT_YEAR-$CURRENT_MONTH-$CURRENT_DATE"
    ],
    "description": "Header for Quarto File"
    }
```

Comment: @JialeDu IIRC there is a forced delay in being able to do that when you answer your own question.

Comment: Yes, there is a waiting time.